# Regex match any string not containing dot character

Tags: regex

for example match any folder name except files that have dot(.) before extension
I try `[^\.]` and `.+[^\.].*` nothing work

Comment: Is this a php question?  What is your language/environment.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to anchor it:

```
^[^.]+$
```

That will match a string composed of any characters except for dots. Is that what you mean by "before extension"? If you mean "at the beginning", then `^[^.]` will do the trick.

But if this isn't, say, grep or something, and you have an actual programming language, this might be better accomplished there. (And even with grep it’s better to write just `grep -v '^\.'`, for example.)

Answer (score 7):

Try `^[^.]+$`.  BTW, you don't need to escape dot inside [].

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
^[^.]+$
```

### [Demo Regex](http://regexr.com?33b3a)

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
^[^.]+$
```

or

```
^(?!.*\.).*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with regex for that, which is expensive. Here's a faster example (in php)

```
foreach($files as $file)
{
    // ignore dot files
    if( 0 === strpos($file,'.') ) continue;
    ...
}
```